# Function is returning a different value each time it is called. How do I make it only change each time it while loop loops?

Tags: python, function, logic-error

I am essentially making a text game of rock paper scissors vs the computer (random generated number) that stops when each player reaches 10 points for my class. I believe every time I call the compPick() function that it changes. This is problematic as the game is no longer works as intended.

```py
#Rock, Paper, Scissors created by Manpreet Singh
from random import randint

userScore = 0
compScore = 0 

def compPick(): #generates a rand num 1-3 then returns that as the corresponding option
    guess = randint(1,3)
    if guess == 1:
        guess = 'Rock'
    elif guess == 2:
        guess = 'Paper'
    else:
        guess = 'Scissors'
        
    return guess


while userScore != 10 or compScore != 10:
    userPick = input("Rock, Paper or Scissors: ")
    print(compPick()) #print for debug
    userPick = userPick.title()
    
    if userPick == compPick():#Both pick the same
        print("Draw! No points.")
    elif userPick == 'Rock' and compPick()== 'Paper':
        print(compPick()) #print for debug
        compScore += 1
        print(f"+1 point for computer! \nC:{compScore} U:{userScore}")
    elif userPick == 'Paper' and compPick()== 'Rock':
        userScore += 1
        print(f"+1 point for computer! \nC:{compScore} U:{userScore}")
    elif userPick == 'Rock' and compPick()== 'Scissors':
        userScore += 1
        print(f"+1 point for computer! \nC:{compScore} U:{userScore}")
    elif userPick == 'Scissors' and compPick()== 'Rock':
        print(compPick()) #print for debug
        compScore += 1
        print(f"+1 point for computer! \nC:{compScore} U:{userScore}")
    elif userPick == 'Paper' and compPick()== 'Scissors':
        print(compPick()) #print for debug
        compScore += 1
        print(f"+1 point for computer! \nC:{compScore} U:{userScore}")
    elif userPick == 'Scissor' and compPick()== 'Paper':
        userScore += 1
        print(f"+1 point for computer! \nC:{compScore} U:{userScore}")
    else:
        print('error')
```

Comment: "I believe every time I call the compPick() function that it changes." yes, because the **purpose of** that function is to get a random value that potentially changes each time. "This is problematic as the game is no longer works as intended." Did you try using a variable to remember the value, and using that for the logic? (And please **ask a question**; don't make us guess.)

Comment: Its output is based on a random number. Why would you expect its output **not** to change? I'm confused

Comment: There is no question in this question. See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a variable that stores the compPick() result and use that to compare against the userPick. Otherwise you are correct, it will regenerate every time you call the compPick() function/method.

Comment: I have tried that and seems to work, the only problem is (unless the logic in my if statements is wrong) I have weird instances for example this output **Rock, Paper or Scissors: paper _ Computer: Rock _ Draw! No points.**

Comment: @ManpreetSingh Are you printing the computer's choice from the variable or from the method? It sounds like it is still from the method.